# Why do I get "(standard_in) 2: syntax error" for my command?

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of custom commands. One is called `Shut`. I use it to automate some tasks before shutting down my PC.

```
#!/bin/bash

. Load

Stop
Update
Install
SpecialCommands

sudo shutdown -h now
```

And when I run it, I get `(standard_in) 2: syntax error` for the `Stop` command. This is my `Stop` command:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo echo

. Load

clear

Divide
Info "Stopping all ..."
Divide

for i in $(docker ps -a -q --filter name=$1); 
do 
    export Name=$(docker container inspect $i | grep "Name.*/" | cut -d'/' -f2 | cut -d'"' -f1)
    docker rm $i --force 1>/dev/null
    Check $Name
done

docker system prune --force 1>/dev/null

Divide
Success "Stopped all"
Divide
```

Basically `Stop` command stops all of the docker containers and cleans the system.

If I change it to `bash Stop` then I won't get that error.

I searched and almost all posts were related to `bc` command. I'm not using `bc`. What could be the reason?

Please tell me if you need more data. Thanks.

**Update**: My `Load` command basically loads a bunch of shell scripts that contain functions to be accessible to commands:

```
for ScriptFile in /HolismHolding/Scripts/**; 
do
    if [[ $ScriptFile == *Python* ]]; then
        continue;
    fi
    . "$ScriptFile"
done
```

For example, it loads my `Message` script that includes these functions:

```
#!/bin/bash

red=""
green=""
cyan=""
magenta=""
yellow=""
reset=""

if [[ -t 1 ]]; then
    red=`tput setaf 1`
    green=`tput setaf 2`
    cyan=`tput setaf 6`
    magenta=`tput setaf 5`
    yellow=`tput setaf 3`
    reset=`tput sgr0`
fi

Check="\xE2\x9C\x94"

function Check()
{
    echo -e "${green}$*;$Check${reset}" | column -t -s ';'
}

function Success()
{
    echo "${green}$*${reset}"
}

function Info()
{
    echo "${cyan}$*${reset}"
}

function Warning()
{
    echo "${yellow}$*${reset}"
}

function Error()
{
    echo "${red}$*${reset}"
}

function Divide()
{
    echo
    echo "${magenta}----------${reset}"
    echo
}
```

Comment: Does your `. Load` include any `eval`s or anything that would attempt to execute shell command(s) piped in from standard input? Have you tried adding `set -x` to the beginning of your `Stop` script, so any commands executed will also be displayed in their final form? That should let you see the exact command line that triggers the error.

Comment: @telcoM, the `Update` and `Install` and other commands also have `. Load` at the beginning of them. I'll post the `Load` command.

Comment: @telcoM, that `set -x` is very helpful. I'm investigating it now. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: that does indeed look like the error message from `bc`, most shells give more useful output and at least somewhat try to tell what the problem was.